# How to convert JSON file to return one step deeper

Tags: json, httpclient, fetch

Hello i want to take the response one step deeper in JSON and save it to list 
See the image
[image]

i want the first response {items: Array(2)} to be like the response in the blue bar.
i want to respond just the line which is underlined in red(2) [ {..} , {..} ] but not changing the backend.
Is it posible
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer to your question is **Yes**.
You need to take the items from the json response and use  `JSON.stringify()` function and make a new json object which has the items entries. Here is the simple demonstration.

```
let json_object= {
    items: [{"id": "name"}, {"id": "name"}, {"id": "name"}]
};

let json_object2 = JSON.stringify(json_object.items);


console.log(json_object2);
```